# not able to add value to the fields shown in the Properties window for the selected widget in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview

In eclipse,In `graphical layout view` of the `xml`, i am selecting a `widget` for example `button` and i am trying to add value to the `weight` field in the Properties `window` and a `pop-up window` is coming  when attempting to type in these fields but value is not getting entered or saved...
Please tell me how to add value to `weight` field or any other field from the properties `window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please elaborate your question with images however I am showing you how to set value in the properties using graphical view 
[image]

hopefully it will help you thanks

Comment: when i am searching in google i got this clue "On some platforms, you will get a pop-up window when attempting to type in these fields. This popup
is a workaround for a known bug. Unfortunately, the workaround will not allow you to enter a
value. So, if this happens, save your file and switch to the XML and edit the code"

Comment: they are telling it is a bug, but they did not tell how to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

Hi below is the screen shot, I selected margin properties and started entering value 16 so a pop window came as below in the bottom right corner but when i select the value its not getting saved... what to do?

[image]